# Samsung T1 Portable SSD as a boot drive

Tags: boot

I have always kept a cloned copy of my OS in a separate secure location away from my desktop. I have just cloned my copy of Windows 7 [Ultimate] to my new Samsung T1 SSD. The cloning [Macrium Reflect] was no problem. I then altered the boot sequence to Samsung T1, CD, HDD. The T1 is easily recognised and I have no trouble in making it number 1 in the sequence. 
[I also boot my Linux OS from a USB so I know that the procedure works]

But, sadly, not in this case with the T1. The boot sequence bypasses the USB option and goes straight through to an error screen where I can select a normal or safe boot for my Windows 7 OS.

So, my question, please, is what am I missing???

PS: I am aware of the Trim situation with a USB, but as I mentioned, this is not to be an active OS, just a static [safety backup] solution which will be overwritten every week or two. If I can ever get it to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't allow os to run from removable device...
If you want run from T1 then use win to go, or find way to modify T1 to be recognized as non removable device. (I remember seeing how to do it somewhere, but it definitely wasn't for average users.)

Comment: Are you sure about that? I run Windows from a removable device without any special attention needed.

Comment: Whel, I am. Because win installer does not allow to install on removable device, if it allow, then it see it as noremovable.